# Xcode does not symbolicates crash log automatically

Tags: xcode, crash-reports

There are many tutorials how to symbolicate crash log manually using given dsym file. But, why should I do that? Application built with release configuration, it crashes. I fetched the log via Window -> Devices -> View Device Logs, but the log is partially symbolicated. For example:

```
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000018297eb30 write + 8
1   MyApp                           0x00000001002f69fc 0x100064000 + 2697724
```

atos command is working fine, but I expect Xcode will perform such thing automatically.
Why everything is symbolicated, but my code is not? How should I change building settings?